# Paths not recognized using Gin with API Gateway (HTTP api), Serverless Framework and Lambda Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda function which uses Gin and has two routes created:

```
func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {

    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "/ hello test completed successfully"})
    })
    r.GET("/hello-world", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "/hello-world hello test completed successfully"})
    })

    return r
}

func main() {
    log.Fatal(gateway.ListenAndServe(":8080", setupRouter()))
}
```

When I follow [this tutorial](https://blog.canopas.com/golang-serverless-microservices-with-gin-f3c2a4943a6d) and manually create a REST API from the AWS console and attach it to this Lambda these two routes work fine, however what I automate the process through the Serverless Framework it doesn't work. I've tried setting up both an HTTP API and REST API with Serverless but neither worked.

I've looked around a lot for the past couple hours and even found [this post](https://forum.serverless.com/t/is-catch-all-path-variables-of-api-gateway-supported/1479) suggesting that it's doable, but for some reason I can't get it work.

What configuration am I missing?